# .replace method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

i want to replace class me to old when user clicks on a tag, i want to do that only with .replace function. My purpose to learn how replace method work. But the function which i have made not working.

```
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('class').replace('me','old')
    })
})  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="me">click</a>
</body>
```

Comment: You can start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: "i want to do that only with" -- is there a **real reason** for this requirement?

Comment: If you want to learn how to use `.replace()` do it in the right context. Adding/removing classes is really completely unrelated to string manipulation, which is the purpose of `.replace()`

Comment: If you want to focus on [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), start by not using jQuery.

Comment: seriously, what's the point? Just do it the natural way, and get moving along.

Comment: if you need to learn, ask a question on that or study yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting the class and it doesn't effect the class attribute, you can replace the string then set it to the element:

```
 $('a').click(function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr('class').replace('me','old')
    $(this).removeClass('me').addClass(cls)
    })
})
```

Comment: Why not use `removeClass` + `addClass` instead?

Comment: @zerkms just to make sure the class is removed. i will update the answer.

Comment: Any reason to use string functions instead of `.addClass('me').removeClass('old')`?

Answer (score 3):

replace is not a jQuery function it is a function of string.  You can read more about replace [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).  To use replace, you can read the attribute as a string, replace the contents of the string and then add the attribute back.

I don't think it is the best way to do this if you have jQuery loaded. You can use the jQuery utility designed to do these manipulations, like so:

```
 $(this).toggleClass('me old');
```

This will turn on and off (toggle) both those class names.  In effect it will switch from one to the other.

Docs:

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: he said specifically to use replace

Comment: @think123: and his requirement makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){


    $('a').click(function(){

        var theclass = $(this).attr('class');
        theclass = theclass.replace('me', 'old');
        $(this).attr('class', theclass);


        })


    })



</script>


</head>

<body>

<a href="#" class="me">click</a>

</body>
```

That should do the trick. [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/think123/PsNra/3/)

Comment: at least tell me so I can improve!

Comment: Don't know for sure but it could be: 1)You got the down vote when you had the typo, good bet people will down vote an answer which does not work. 2) The fiddle you link too does not work nor show the functionality.  Since you edited the typo I gave you a +1 to get back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#" class="old">click</a>');
});
```

I have created a bin with the solution on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpco